# Android Webview index.html from server loading xxx.jpg from local

Tags: android, android-webview, local-storage, assets

I've to load a page index.php from a server.  I wan't to load local files from assets folder in my project, but it doesn't work.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    final Activity _activity = this;

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    webview.setWebViewClient(new myWebViewClient());

    webview.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
    webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);

    webview.loadUrl("http://192.168.0.11/mypage.php");

            webview.setWebViewClient(new myWebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)      {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            progressBar.show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                String description, String failingUrl) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            progressBar.dismiss();
        }
    });
    }
```

In my HTML page some local images are loaded like this :

```
<img src="file:///android_asset/image.jpg" width="200">
```

but the image is not displayed.

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks,

André.

Comment: check your `image name and . extension is .jpg ,are you sure ? And also remove width and test it !!! `

Comment: Picture extention is correct, and I've checked without the size... doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

no need to give whole path like from file to assets..if html file  which you want to display and the image both are in same directory of the assets directory thn jst give the file name

```
<img id="loadimage" src="ic_launcher.png" height="100px" width="100px" />
```

ic_launcher.png file is in assets folder